# Ensure a value is present at most "n" times in a table cell. DBMS side approach

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique

Which are common approaches to ensure data consistence, at DBMS side (I mean involving only the DBMS), in the case the requirement would be that a value is repeated at most n times?

It would be something like a unicity constraint but allowing a maximum count > 1.

I'm interested in common approach on the Mysql DBMS, but I suppose could be very similar in other systems.

I would avoid to use software side solutions, external to the DBMS itself.

Comment: It is possible to use Calculated Cell, which will include a CASE statement for ```SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable WHERE column = "yourValue"``` to compare with your maxValue and gives value. Also you can create stored procedure and run this procedure to ensure this process.

Comment: Or use triggers for such constraint like requirements.

Comment: 'the requirement would be that a value is repeated at most n times' - can you give an example please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, in MySQL, you would do this using a trigger.

The most recent versions of MySQL support check constraints.  This allows you to:

- Maintain an "entity" count in a separate table using triggers (+1 for insert, -1 for delete).
- Add a check constraint so that value never exceeds your threshold.

I prefer this method to doing the entire check in a trigger.  At least the threshold is clear in the `check` constraint.

Comment: How is this feature called in newest mysql versions? What about data integrity in high concurrency scenarios? Could I ask you to write a code example in the response? Many thanks.